# Activating iPod that is linked to another Apple ID — previous owner not available

Tags: ipod-touch, apple-id, find-my-iphone, activation-lock

I bought an iPod off of ebay, and went to activate it. However, it was linked to another person's Apple ID and I have no contact with them. The ebay seller does not have the Apple ID either. Is there anyway around activating this iPod without contact with the original owner whose Apple ID this iPod is linked to?